# Web site still accessible after deleting OpenShift app (with Tomcat 7 cartidge)

Tags: tomcat7, openshift

I've deleted several OpenShift apps (all of them with Tomcat 7 cartridges) with `rhc app delete <app>`. (`rhc apps` now reports `No applications.`)

But the apps nevertheless seem still alive at `http://<app>-<domain>/rhcloud.com`.

Is this a feature or a bug? How can I make these web sites go away permanently?

Comment: By now it looks as if the web site will go away after some time (hours).